# BeautifulSoup cannot bring <body>'s contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image]
http://bus.asan.go.kr/web/bus_arrInfo_pop?busStopId=288000830

The link is the bus information system page provided by a Korean local government.
I want to crawl the information on the page. but I couldn't.
When I tried using BeautifulSoup, Some codes were read but other parts weren't.

My code is as below.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://bus.asan.go.kr/web/bus_arrInfo_pop?busStopId=288000863")

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
print(bsObj)
```

and the result is below.
There are no any body-contents in the result.
What should I do to get contents from the page?
Thank you in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<title>아산시 버스정보시스템</title>
<link href="../resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../resources/css/w/scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../resources/css/w/bus_arrInfo_pop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="../resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/hashMap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/w/commonTraffic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
                var paramStop_id = '288000863';
                if(paramStop_id != "" && paramStop_id != null){
                        var form_data = {
                                        busStopId: paramStop_id
            };

                ajaxCall("../mobile/traffic/searchBusStopRoute", form_data, ajaxBeforeSendMapRouteInfo, ajaxSuccessMapRouteInfo);
                }

                $('.btn_print').click(function(){
                        $('.stationInfo_wrap .cont').css('max-height','inherit');
                        $('.stationInfo_wrap .cont').css('overflow-y','auto');
                        window.print();
                        $('.stationInfo_wrap .cont').css('max-height','670px');
                        $('.stationInfo_wrap .cont').css('overflow-y','scroll');
                });
        });

        function ajaxBeforeSendMapRouteInfo(xhr){
                var strTemp = "";
                strTemp += "<div style='height: 144px;width: 573px;border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;'><img style='width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-top:60px;' alt='로딩중' src='../resources/images/w/loader.gif'></div>";
                $("#map_route_data").empty().append(strTemp);
        }

        function ajaxSuccessMapRouteInfo(data){
                var strTemp = "";
                var stopInfo = data.stopInfo;
                if(data.busStopRouteList.length == 0){
                        var id = stopInfo.service_id;
                        if(id==""||id==null||id==" "){
                                id = "ID 없음";
                        }

                        $("#map_service_id").text("[" + id + "]");
                        $("#map_stop_name").text(stopInfo.stop_name);

                        strTemp += "<div style='height: 152px;width: 573px;border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;line-height: 144px;'>검색결과가 없습니다.</div>";
                } else {
                        var id = data.busStopRouteList[0].service_id;
                        if(id==""||id==null||id==" "){
                                id = "ID 없음";
                        }
                        $("#map_service_id").text("[" + id + "]");
                        $("#map_stop_name").text(data.busStopRouteList[0].stop_name);

                        $.each( data.busStopRouteList, function( index, value ) {
                                var routeName = value.route_name;
                                if(value.relay_areacode==285){
                                        routeName = routeName + " (천안)";
                                }
                                if(index==0){
                                        if(value.eb_flag==0){
                                                strTemp += "<div class='st_busNum'>"+routeName+"</div>";
                                        }else{
                                                if(value.route_type == 11) {
                                                        strTemp += "<div class='st_busNum'>"+routeName+"</div>";
                                                }else {
                                                        strTemp += "<div class='st_busNum'>"+routeName+"</div>";
                                                }
                                        }
                                        strTemp += "<div class='st_waitTime'>"+value.provide_type+"</div><div class='st_where'>"+value.rstop+"</div><div class='st_XXX'>"+value.last_stop_name+"</div>";

                                        if(index!=(data.busStopRouteList.length-1)){
                                                line=1;
                                        }else{
                                                //strTemp += "<div class='st_waitTime'></div><div class='st_where'></div><div class='st_XXX' style='margin-bottom:6px;'></div>";
                                                line=2;
                                        }
                                        temp_route_id=value.route_id;
                                }else{
                                        if(temp_route_id==value.route_id){
                                                //strTemp += "<div class='st_waitTime line2'>"+value.provide_type+"</div><div class='st_where line2'>"+value.rstop+"</div><div class='st_XXX line2'>"+value.last_stop_name+"</div>";
                                                line=2;
                                                temp_route_id="-1";
                                        }else{
                                                if(line==1){
                                                        //strTemp += "<div class='st_waitTime
line2'></div><div class='st_where line2'></div><div class='st_XXX line2'></div>";
                                                        temp_route_id="-1";
                                                        line=2;
                                                }
                                                if(value.eb_flag==0){
                                                        strTemp += "<div class='st_busNum'>"+routeName+"</div>";
                                                }else{
                                                        if(value.route_type == 11) {
                                                                strTemp += "<div class='st_busNum'>"+routeName+"</div>";
                                                        }else {
                                                                strTemp += "<div class='st_busNum'>"+routeName+"</div>";
                                                        }
                                                }

                                                if(index!=(data.busStopRouteList.length-1)){
                                                        strTemp += "<div class='st_waitTime'>"+value.provide_type+"</div><div class='st_where'>"+value.rstop+"</div><div class='st_XXX'>"+value.last_stop_name+"</div>";
                                                        line=1;
                                                }else{
                                                        strTemp += "<div class='st_waitTime'>"+value.provide_type+"</div><div class='st_where'>"+value.rstop+"</div><div class='st_XXX' style='margin-bottom:10px;'>"+value.last_stop_name+"</div>";
                                                        //strTemp += "<div class='st_waitTime'></div><div class='st_where'></div><div class='st_XXX' style='margin-bottom:10px;'></div>";
                                                        line=2;
                                                }

                                                temp_route_id=value.route_id;
                                        }
                                }
                        });

                }
                $("#map_route_data").empty().append(strTemp);
        }

        </script>
</meta></head>
<body style="width:100%;min-width:615px;">
<div class="wrap" style="width:615px;">
<div class="stationInfo_wrap">
<div class="st_header">
<div class="st_info">
<p>
<span id="map_service_id"></span>
<span id="map_stop_name" style="padding-left: 5px;"></span>
<a class="btn_print extraBtnBg" href="#" style="  margin-top: 13px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 19px; width:90px;">도착정보 출력</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
<div class="st_title">
<div class="st_busNum">노선번호</div>
<div class="st_waitTime">도착예정</div>
<div class="st_where">현재위치</div>
<div class="st_XXX">현재정류장</div>
</div>
<div class="st_list">
<div class="map_route_data" id="map_route_data">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BS doesn't run JavaScript, it only processes the static HTML.

Comment: The website uses AJAX to get all the details. Instead of trying to scrape it, you should call the same API that the website uses.

Comment: I appreciate your fantastic comment, I become to know what I study from now on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://bus.asan.go.kr/web/bus_arrInfo_pop?busStopId=288000863'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

output = ''
blacklist = [
    '[document]',
    'noscript',
    'header',
    'html',
    'meta',
    'head', 
    'input',
    'script',
    # there may be more elements you don't want, such as "style", etc.
]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)

print(output)
```

result:

'아산시 버스정보시스템\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n도착정보 출력\n\n\n\n\n\n노선번호\n도착예정\n현재위치\n현재정류장\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'

you can also replace \n if you want.

sourcecode from:https://matix.io/extract-text-from-webpage-using-beautifulsoup-and-python/

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness, but it only crawls table header on the image, not the contents...